# New to Linux - Need Suggestions on Hardware that is compatiable

Tags: networking, server, backup, raid

I want to either build a tower or use my Lenovo TS130 server with Ubuntu.

My goal is to do RAID 1 on the tower and install Ubuntu.

The purpose of this machine is to use it as a file server for my computer store so when my clients bring there computer in, I can somehow access the Linux server by going to my clients browser and typing in " //b " then it would pull up the shared drives on the Linux machine. From there I want to be able to copy and paste files from my customers Windows machines so I can have a backup before I reinstall their operating system.

Does anyone know if the Lenovo TS130 will be compatiable with RAID 1 on Ubuntu? If not is there a machine I can build for like $300 to $500 excluding hard drives that will run fast.

Again my goal is to use this as a network file server so I can copy and paste files onto it to backup my clients information. My goal is to achieve fast local network speed so I am not waiting hours to transfer data on my network.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has a certification program see [Ubuntu Certified hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/)

1. [Ubuntu Desktop certified hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/)
2. [Ubuntu Server certified hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/server/)